# How can I get everything in alias rewritten from http://hostname/ to http://hostname/alias/?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, mod-alias, frapi

I have FRAPI framework installed on the windows server in the intranet under apache alias.

```
# Frontend
Alias /api "D:/var/www/api_dev/public" 

# Backend
Alias /api_admin "D:/var/www/api_dev/admin/public"
```

The .htaccess file for admin part looks like this:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

The problem is that all actions, scripts and css are not rewritten.

All of them point to `http://hostname/action`  instead of `http://hostname/api_admin/action`

Script and css are pointing to `http://hostname/css/style.css` and so on.

I added RewriteBase

```
RewriteBase /api_admin
```

But I had no luck.

How can I get everything in alias  rewritten from `http://hostname/` to `http://hostname/api_admin/` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and installed FRAPI under VirtualHost.

```
<VirtualHost *:666>
    ServerName hostname
    DocumentRoot D:/var/www/frapi/public
    ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:777>
    ServerName hostname
    DocumentRoot D:/var/www/frapi/admin/public
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```